# Call a function through jquery ajax

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, jquery

It's been 2 days now and still I can't get this problem to work.
So basically I am trying to call a php function through jquery ajax 
but nothing is working, I am not sure what is the problem is...
here are my codes

the ajax

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#idCheck1").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'../../../../Controller/PostsController.php', 
            data: {action: 'update_checkbox'},
            success:function(result){
//                $("#dsa").html(result);
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

the view

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create("Posts", array("action" => "update_checkbox", "id" => "checkingBox")) ?>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                        echo $this->Form->input('Post.' . $i . '.id', array("type" => "hidden", "label" => false, "value" => $sum['posts']['id']))
                        ?>
                        <?php
                        echo $this->Form->input('Post.' . $i . '.done', array("type" => "checkbox", "label" => false, "value" => "1", "id" => "idCheck1"))
                        ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $i++;
            }
            ?>

        </table>
        <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

the controller

```
 public function update_checkbox() {
        //    debug($this->data);
        $var = $this->Post->saveCheckBox($this->data);
        $this->set("result", $var);
    }
```

the model

```
public function saveCheckBox($checkbox) {
        debug($checkbox);
        $this->saveAll($checkbox['Post']);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it yourself. If yes where does it go wrong? E.g. is the request being made, if yes what is the result, etc.

Comment: Can you access this url in the browser: `url:'../../../../Controller/PostsController.php'`?

Comment: What is the actual problem. Have you confirmed that .click(function(){ is firing.... confirmed that a HTTP request is being made to PostsController.php? ...  try adding an 

errror:function(result){} on the $.ajax with an alert to see if you have any other helpful info.

Comment: Have you tried to debug to determine if request sent to the server?

Answer (score 2):

The url

```
url:'../../../../Controller/PostsController.php'
```

looks wrong. Since this is an AJAX request that goes through the browser you can't use relative paths that try to go upwards in the folder hierarchy, as browsers url's don't work that way. You should be making that request so that it is passed through a web server, i.e. the url should look like one of the following:

```
url:'http://localhost/Controller/PostsController.php'
```

or

```
url:'/Controller/PostsController.php'
```

The first option is an absolute url, but this also makes the code a bit less flexible (suppose you change the domain from localhost to something else). The second option is a relative URL, but one that is relative to the domain root of your web server (i.e. in the example it would still resolve to localhost/Controller...).

In both cases based on what you've posted, your PHP file should live in a Controller/ folder in the document root of your site. The structure of your code however suggests that you are using a framework of some kind (e.g. Zend, Symfony or CodeIgniter)? If that is the case it would be helpful if you post information on what framework you're using as well as that might change the answer.

**UPDATE**

In the case of cakePHP, you should access the controller through the front controller, meaning the URL should look like this:

```
url:'/posts'
```

**UPDATE 2**

For the jquery side, a complete ajax request example could look like this:

```
$(".idCheck").click(
   function(){ 
      var idVal = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({ 
         url:'/posts/update_checkbox', 
         data: {id: idVal }, 
         type: 'POST', 
         success:function(result){ 
            $("#dsa").html(result); 
         } 
      }); 
  });
```

Note that the URL already contains the update_checkbox action (i.e. the complete url to the action you want to execute), and the data object contains the value of the clicked element that you want to send to the server. If you want to send a complete form you could also use $('#myformselector').serialize() to convert all inputs in the form to a object suitable for the data property of the ajax request.

Comment: **Never ever use absolute paths**, e.g.: `http://localhost/Controller/PostsController.php`. If you are moving the files to the production environment or another domain all your URLs stop working. Extra emphasize for OP :-)

Comment: "it would be helpful if you post information on what framework you're using" -> question is tagged cake

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've tried to changed the url. But either of the two is not working :( So when I debugged in chrome this showed the error http://i49.tinypic.com/slmmwl.jpg

Comment: @Catherine try using /posts as the url instead and see if it still returns a 404 error. You're working with a framework that does (or should do) url rewriting, meaning requests going to a certain URL will be rewritten internally to point to a certain PHP file. See the CakePHP manual for more info.

Comment: @JensWegar ok thanks. I'll do that. Thanks for the reply everyone :)

Comment: @JensWegar So what I did is     
$(".idCheck").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'update_checkbox',
//                        data: {
//                            action: 'update_checkbox'
//                        },
            type: 'POST',

            success:function(result){
            //                $("#dsa").html(result);
            }
        });
    });

It is not working the way I want it to be. It says "array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given"
Any thoughts?

Comment: @Catherine See the update 2 for a example jquery request that should at least access your controller correctly. The error about array_keys would suggest that your error happens on the PHP side. Looking at the code for the controller, id say this line: $var = $this->Post->saveCheckBox($this->data); should look like this: $var = $this->Post->saveCheckBox($this->request->data); (note the $this->request->data part).

Comment: @JensWegar thanks again for your reply. But still the problem is still the same :(

the debugged output in chrome

http://i49.tinypic.com/2wqsvpj.jpg

Comment: Ok, you'll need to solve the notice message about the undefined Post index (always when debugging PHP, start with the first notice/warning/error you get, because that often is the cause of other possible errors later on). My guess is there's something with this line of code in the model: $this->saveAll($checkbox['Post']);
What does the $checkbox variable actually contain? You can trace that e.g. by doing var_dump($checkbox) at the beginning of the saveCheckBox function.

Comment: @JensWegar Sorry for the late reply, yep I changed the line code $var = $this->Post->saveCheckBox($this->data); to 
$var = $this->Post->saveCheckBox($this->request->data); but the problem is still the same. I don't know why :((

Comment: I'm out of ideas here now, CakePHP is not familiar enough that I would know where to look anymore. All I can say is follow common PHP debugging practices. I.e. check that variables contain what you expect them to contain, check that functions get called. Try using dummy data first before using your model or the post values, etc.

Comment: this thread has been solved thanks Jens Wegar for all your reply :)

Comment: np :) Would be great if you can give an explanation of what the actual problem was in the end and how you solved it, for future reference.

Comment: here's what I did                                                                     $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#idCheck1").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'update_checkbox',  type: 'POST', 
           // data: {action: 'update_checkbox'},
            success:function(result){
//                $("#dsa").html(result);
            } 
        });
    });
});